# Symfony two forms for the same entity in the same page

Tags: symfony

I'm using the createFormBuilder function twice on the same page which work with the same entity. My problem is that only the first generated form is detected by Symfony as a form, so I can't use the method `$form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()` for my second form when the forms are submitted.

My guess is that it's because the hidden tokens corresponding to the CSRF field are identical for the two forms.

Is there a way to generate a different token for the second form without deactivating it ?

The two generated forms in my view

```
<form name="form" method="post" class="form-delete-confirm">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
    <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="h0i7WF2uQxi376ZF4kMm4TbuD0cE8TYPhWP9b-oNqJ4" />
</form>

<form name="form" method="post" class="form-post-confirm">
    <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="h0i7WF2uQxi376ZF4kMm4TbuD0cE8TYPhWP9b-oNqJ4" />
</form>
```

I have two methods which generate each form for example

```
public function createParticipantPostForm($meetingId = null, $userId = null)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, ['attr' => ['class' => 'form-post-confirm']]);
        // The action is null when one form is created form the modal, it is then defined thanks to the user click
        if (null !== $meetingId && null !== $userId) {
            $form = $form->setAction(
                $this->generateUrl(
                    'meeting_participant_create', [
                        'meeting_id' => $meetingId,
                        'user_id' => $userId,
                    ]
                )
            );
        }

        return $form->setMethod('POST')->getForm();
    }
```

The other is exactly the same except `setMethod('DELETE')`, the class attribute and the route in the generateUrl method

The two methods are executed in my controller and the form views are send to the view.

Comment: You can see the csrf tokens for every form in the source page to see if are identical. My guess is that they are not identical. Also, can you post some code to see your abordation?

Comment: I edited my question